# Android Studio (Intellij Idea) - run/debug configuration - remembering which device to run on

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I guess this is a bit of a longshot, but with Eclipse, if you were using an Android emulator which was not the included one (for example, VirtualBox), you could select it the first time you ran your program, and tick a checkbox saying "Use this device for future launches". But the same option does not exist in Android Studio (Intellij Idea), meaning you have to choose the emulator every time you want to run the program.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any way I can hack this so it will always run on a particular emulator which is not the built-in emulator. Can I put the emulator's ip address and port into a config file somewhere so the program will always launch on it without me having to click? I know it's a small thing but it's just convenience.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `Prefer Android Virtual Device` value in the configuration settings?

Comment: Thanks, but this only includes devices handled by the Android Virtual Device Manager, which are run on the inbuilt emulator. It doesn't include devices on other emulators connected via adb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to select USB device as the default. The program will then automatically run on the connected Virtualbox emulator. [The answer was provided by sasha_trn in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616185/android-studio-intellij-idea-run-debug-configuration-remembering-which-dev#comment24102506_16616967)

Answer (score 24):

Sure it does, click the dropdown next to the run config, and press "Edit Configurations"

[image: Run C]

[image: Run Configs]

You can then select an Emulator, A Device, or to ask you when you run the app (like you have now).

Comment: Yes, there is a setting to choose from running devices, but with Eclipse, the first time you chose a device from that list, there was an option to remember what you chose and use it in future without being asked. That's missing from Android Studio - you have to specify the device from the list of running devices every time you run your app. I know it's a very minor quibble, though!

Comment: Oh I see, you mean when you have multiple devices plugged in. If you have only one device plugged in, you don't have to, it will just upload and run

Comment: No, I don't have any devices plugged in, I have one emulated device running, connected with adb. The only way to run my app on this emulated device is to have "show chooser dialog" selected. This means I have to select the emulated device every time I run the app. Eclipse would let me select it once, and remember it.

Comment: No, just click emulator in the screenshot I have shown you and chose it from the drop down. It will never show the chooser dialog then

Comment: Unfortunately that drop-down only shows virtual devices which use the built-in emulator, which you have created with the Android virtual device manager. I am using Virtualbox, connecting with the adb connect command. This only shows up in the "chooser dialog", as a running device. it doesn't show up in the emulator list.

Comment: If you use Android x86 emulator with VirtualBox, you should use USB device. Also I wrote batch file to connect adb to emulator, and put it in Before Launch section (in Windows IDEA there is present option Run External Tool).

Comment: Thank you sasha_trn, selecting USB device does exactly what I want. If you posted that as an answer I would mark it as the correct answer. And that batch file sounds like a good idea too, to make things even more convenient!